# Simple refactoring kills reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data object with a property of

```
displaySubtotal
```

I can update that property's value with:

```
data.displaySubtotal = numPad.valueAsAString();
```

My method, valueAsAString(), is:

```
var valueAsAString = function() {
    var value = makeValue();

    if (value) {
        return value;
    }
    return 0;

};
```

OK, so the problem comes when I try to abstract that function like so:

```
var valueAsAString = function() {
    var value = makeValue();

    func(value);

};

var func = function(x) {
    if (x) {
        return x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At which point it no longer updates the displaySubtotal property. The displaySubtotal property is reported as undefined.

But why?

isn't my refactoring correct?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't return anything for `valueAsAString = function() {}`. change to `return func(value)` then should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your refactored `valueAsAString` function never returns anything. A function without a `return` statement will return `undefined` by default, which is why `numPad.valueAsAString()` is `undefined`.

Inside `valueAsAString`, just change

```js
    func(value);
```

to

```js
    return func(value);
```

And your function should work.